# Open site using default Browser Language Preference,developed in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We are developing multilingual site using SharePoint 2007. Now the requirement from client is whenerevr user access the site, the Site should be open in his browser using users browser Language Preference. Our current site is in English and Spanish. If users language preference is Spanish then Spanish site should be display to the user.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop a redirector module which will read the browser settings on the redirect.aspx page (Example) and then redirect to the appropriate language site based on thei site.

See here for the example:

http://panvega.wordpress.com/2008/05/15/variationrootlandig-redirect-to-another-variation-site/